# What does the error "section type conflict" mean with respect to gcc?

Tags: gcc

I am compiling a source file using a bare metal Xtensa gcc compiler. This conflict is between a const and non const variable when placed in the same section.

Searched the net a lot but there is no definition on what this error means.

Answer (score 3):

Const variables are given a read-only section attribute, and non-const ones get the writable attribute.  A given section cannot be both read-only and writable, thus the conflict.